# Xorg crashes everytime after unlocking desktop on Xubuntu 17.10

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, login, crash

I have recently reinstalled my Lenovo Thinkpad T440p with Xubuntu 17.10. Whenever I leave my desk, I lock the screen by pressing Ctrl + Alt + Del. When I return (no matter if it's after a few minutes or an hour), I can normally enter my password on the lock screen, but then Xorg crashes and my session is lost. I can briefly see a TTY, then I am thrown back to the login screen and can log in normally to an "empty" session. Ubuntu gives me the "Internal system error" message, which tells me that Xorg has crashed.

I have uploaded an excerpt from /var/log/syslog here: https://paste.ee/p/kRmHr - it starts with the first entry in a few minutes (after locking the computer)
and ends when the new session has started. And here's the crash log file, apparently the same thing Ubuntu shows in that error message after logging in: https://paste.ee/p/FiTP1, but with the core dump removed. I can provide more logs, of course.

Note that I uninstalled Spotify after reading the log, because I was a bit surprised that it showed up there, but the error persists, so it probably hasn't got anything to do with that.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked for any available software updates?

Comment: Yes, everything is up to date.

Comment: Submit a bug using `ubuntu-bug` (to automatically attach diagnostic info).